# Golang reverse proxy to app behind nginx

Tags: networking, nginx, go, reverse-proxy

I am writing a simple reverse proxy with Golang. The code is listed below:

```
func NewMultiHostProxy(target_urls []string) gin.HandlerFunc {
    var urls []*url.URL
    for i := 0; i < len(target_urls); i++ {
        target, err := url.Parse(target_urls[i])
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Errorf("Error parsing url")
            return nil
        }
        urls = append(urls, target)
    }
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        director := func(req *http.Request) {
            target := urls[rand.Int()%len(urls)]
            r := c.Request
            req = r
            req.URL.Scheme = target.Scheme
            req.URL.Host = target.Host
            req.URL.Path = target.Path
            req.Header.Set("X-GoProxy", "GoProxy")
            if target.RawQuery == "" || req.URL.RawQuery == "" {
                req.URL.RawQuery = target.RawQuery + req.URL.RawQuery
            } else {
                req.URL.RawQuery = target.RawQuery + "&" + req.URL.RawQuery
            }
            log.Print(req.URL)
        }
        proxy := &httputil.ReverseProxy{Director: director}
        proxy.ServeHTTP(c.Writer, c.Request)
    }
}
```

When I am trying to proxy one request to a REST api behind Nginx, Nginx always returns 404. However, if i directly access the REST api, it returns the result correctly. Here's my Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  myservername;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

May I know how to debug this problem? Is it caused by Nginx configuration?

Answer (score 2):

From https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy:

```
    // Director must be a function which modifies
    // the request into a new request to be sent
    // using Transport. Its response is then copied
    // back to the original client unmodified.
    // Director must not access the provided Request
    // after returning.
    Director func(*http.Request)
```

That is the function used to construct ReverseProxy in `&httputil.ReverseProxy{Director: director}`

But your `director` **never modifies** the `http.Request` that original `req` points to. It reassigns the pointer with `req = r`. An irrelevant `http.Request` is modified instead.

Comment: Hi @cshu, thanks for the prompt reply. I have remove the reassign code but the 404 error persists. In the Nginx log, there is a record for the access, so the proxy request can reach the target, however, the nginx log shows 404.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with request body. If you look into how `Gin` implement get parameter, you will find that it open, read it and close it. So when you forward the request, the request body is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same issue. I solved it by setting the Host. nginx uses the host(server_name) to decide which server on port 80 to serve.

```
req.Host = target.Host
// or
req.Host = ""
```

It can be set to an empty string because the url host was just set `req.URL.Host = target.Host`
https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request

```
    // For client requests Host optionally overrides the Host
    // header to send. If empty, the Request.Write method uses
    // the value of URL.Host. Host may contain an international
    // domain name.
    Host string
```

As a side note, you can create the proxy outside of the gin handler and call `proxy.ServeHTTP(c.Writer, c.Request)` in the gin handler. The final result would look like this:

```
func NewMultiHostProxy(target_urls []string) gin.HandlerFunc {
    var urls []*url.URL
    for i := 0; i < len(target_urls); i++ {
        target, err := url.Parse(target_urls[i])
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Errorf("Error parsing url")
            return nil
        }
        urls = append(urls, target)
    }
    director := func(req *http.Request) {
        target := urls[rand.Int()%len(urls)]
        req.URL.Scheme = target.Scheme
        req.URL.Host = target.Host
        req.URL.Path = target.Path
        req.Host = ""
        req.Header.Set("X-GoProxy", "GoProxy")
        if target.RawQuery == "" || req.URL.RawQuery == "" {
            req.URL.RawQuery = target.RawQuery + req.URL.RawQuery
        } else {
            req.URL.RawQuery = target.RawQuery + "&" + req.URL.RawQuery
        }
        log.Print(req.URL)
    }
    proxy := &httputil.ReverseProxy{Director: director}
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        proxy.ServeHTTP(c.Writer, c.Request)
    }
}
```